# Avoiding CORS with blazor client and ASP.NET Core service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm just starting with Blazor and using my own ASP.NET Core service as a backend. I'm running both locally off of Visual Studio in Dev mode. I had to enable CORS in the service because with the default config, the Blazor client is served from a different port than the service. What I've noticed is that the service is getting a lot of extra HTTP OPTIONS requests as part of CORS. I want to avoid this extra load on the service, how should I go about that? Is there a way to serve the Blazor from the same port as the service? I suppose this might not be possible if I used a CDN to serve the Blazor in Prod. Am I then forced to have to deal with extraneous OPTIONS requests in production?

Comment: if you are hosting on the same origin, then you dont need to do cors. you shouldn't be concerned about that

Comment: How can I distribute wasm and service from the same origin, including same port?